# jQuery-UI Autocomplete with data source that doesn't have label or value properties

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I've got an array of objects:

```
var people = [
    { name: "John", number: "256", date: "04/08/2013" },
    { name: "Bill", number: "311", date: "04/07/2013" },
    { name: "Mike", number: "127", date: "04/02/2013" }
];
```

I want to add jQuery-UI autocomplete functionality to the following `input` element:

```
<input type="text" id="person-search" />
```

It gets wired up like:

```
$('#person-search').autocomplete({
    source: people
});
```

The jQuery-UI documentation for the autocomplete widget states that I must have label and value properties on each object in the array. I really don't want to go back and add these extra properties. I don't believe that I should have too do that.

**It seems wasteful and wrong to have to mutate my data source in order to satisfy jQuery-UI.**

Is there a way in which I can tell jQuery-UI autocomplete to search the properties `name` and `number` when it is filtering without adding properties to the objects? (these objects are used elsewhere and it could be an array of thousands of elements)

I've noticed the option to provide a function to `source` option, but won't that basically skip the caching and built in, optimized filtering in jQuery-UI autocomplete? Does jQuery UI autocomplete even have those things, or is that a myth? Seems at that point, I might as well just reinvent the wheel pretty much.

There should be an easy way to tell it to use different property names. Am I overlooking something? Am I the only one frustrated by this seemingly obvious feature lacking?

Comment: How is wasteful to have to manipulate your data to satisfy jquery ui's requirements. That's why their documentation exists

Comment: It's wasteful to have to add two additional properties to each object in my array/data source. That is going to consume quite a bit of extra memory, especially when working with large data sets. I shouldn't have to mutate my data source in order to satisfy jQuery-UI's interface. The interface should allow configuration options to satisfy the data source.

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data Looking at their documentation, looks like it is possible.

Comment: @mituw16 Notice how their data source has `value` and `label` properties while mine does not. I'm saying that I should be able to tell jquery-ui autocomplete to use my properties in place of `value` and `label`. So far, the only way I've seen to do that is to offer a function for `source` which looks like it skips over any custom caching that the autocomplete plugin uses.

Comment: Seems like I might be able to hijack the filter function by overriding `$.ui.autocomplete.filter`. Problem is that would change it for all instances of autocomplete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure it's possibile. You can use jQuery [`map`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) to translate your starting item array or object to new array of items, than you can apply the input filter using [`grep`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/).

The current filter is stored in the `request`, [`source`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source) function parameter.

Ref:

> Translate all items in an array or object to new array of items.

and

> Finds the elements of an array which satisfy a filter function. The
>   original array is not affected.

Code:

```
$('#personsearch').autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        var re = $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term);
        var matcher = new RegExp("^" + re, "i");
        response($.grep(($.map(people, function (v, i) {

            return {
                label: v.name,
                value: v.name
            };
        })), function (item) {
            return matcher.test(item.value);
        }))

    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/RKq5n/1/

Comment: I mean no offense, but I specifically mentioned, multiple times, that I didn't want to do it this way. However, after digging through all of the autocomplete source code, I came to the realization that jQuery UI doesn't do any real filter caching. That is, it applies the filter to the entire array of data source items each time a new search is made. So until I find enough free time to write my own autocomplete solution with filter caching built in, this is the solution that I will be stuck with. Maybe I'll fork jQuery-UI autocomplete and add the functionality to specify which properties to use

Comment: @crush no offence :-) I read again your question and I see you requiriment. By now the only solution responding is the one that I have provided. What you want is something not supported, you can implement it by yourself or pull a request

Comment: Yeah, thanks! I'll implement it and send a pull request to the jquery-ui team. We will see if they accept. I'll go ahead and accept this as it is what I ended up doing for now anyways.